# C# Edit Command Name in Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

In my **gridView** I've inserted the **edit command name** for every single row.

Now I need when the database value of **myDate is not null** stopping the edit in this row.

I tried this solution, but in **GV** see the icon *stop.gif* when the database value of **myDate is not null**, but if click in *stop.gif* the edit row is open, why?

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myDate").ToString()) ? "/Images/edit.gif" : "/Images/stop.gif")%>'
                 ToolTip="Edit" /></center>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/update.gif"
                ToolTip="Update" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="/Images/cancel.gif"
                ToolTip="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just make the image url blank, it does not mean that you are not rendering the control. The button will still render. What you could do instead is like below

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" 
     ImageUrl='/Images/stop.gif'
     Visbile =  '<%#Eval("myDate").HasValue %>'    
     ToolTip="Edit" />
```

Comment: thank you for help, I tried your suggestion but I don't have change in my code ... if click in stop.gif the edit row is open ...

Comment: I think I have made a mistake. You need to use !string.IsNullOrEmpty. I have corrected the code above, can you try now?

Comment: Yes I tried now, I see in gv only stop.gif and if click in stop.gif the edit row is open

Comment: Ok. Then check what is the value of (Eval("myDate").ToString()). For the testing you can add one additional column which just prints this value. I think it might be returing 01/01/001. What is the data type of myDate column?

Comment: the data type of myDate column is 2014-07-07 14:42:48

Comment: Assuming that the data type is DateTime? I have changed the code above, can you check again? Basically you need to hide the button when myDate is null